# Circular motion "calculate the angle"

Tags: geometry, physics, circles, education, rotations

I have a equation i need to find out how they hang together.

```
angel = (velocity * time) - (acceleration * time * time / 2)
```

I know circumference of a circle:

```
2*Pi*radius -> (velocity * time)
```

radius is:

```
(velocity * time) / (2 * Pi)
```

But. 
What is this mean:

```
(acceleration * time * time / 2)
```

I think It's look like some kind of velocity.

Any idea ?

Comment: It's the angular displacement caused by angular acceleration.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From what I could figure, you are in the case of circular motion with constant acceleration [see Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Equations_of_motion#Constant_circular_acceleration)

Be careful with your notation, because in this case there are 2 velocities, angular and linear. Angular is independent of the radius (usually denoted as $\omega$) while linear is actually $\omega\cdot r$.

So, probably in your first equation $\theta=\omega\cdot t - \frac{1}{2}a t^2$ 
you are mixing linear and angular quantities.

In any case, to answer the last part, $a$ is the acceleration, i.e. second derivative with respect to time of the angle $\theta$, $\frac{d^2\theta}{dt^2}$, and describes how the angular velocity changes with time.
The $\frac{1}{2}at^2$ is a straightforward derivation from the equations of motion for constant angular acceleration.

Comment: Thanks, will look into it!